# SQLiteConstraintException

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

This is my table-creation-command:

```
private static final String PINGPONG_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_PINGPONG + "(" + COLUMN_ID_PINGPONG + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_CNAME +
            " text not null, " + COLUMN_DATE + " text not null, " + " text not null, " + COLUMN_LEAD + " numeric, " + COLUMN_PLACE + " text not null, " 
            + COLUMN_SET_ONE1 + " numeric, " + COLUMN_SET_ONE2 + " numeric, " + COLUMN_SET_TWO1 + " numeric, " + COLUMN_SET_TWO2 + " numeric, " + COLUMN_SET_THREE1
             + " numeric, " + COLUMN_SET_THREE2 + " numeric, " + COLUMN_SET_FOUR1 + " numeric, " + COLUMN_SET_FOUR2 + " numeric, " + COLUMN_SET_FIVE1  + " numeric, " 
            + COLUMN_SET_FIVE2 + " numeric, " + COLUMN_SET_SIX1 + " numeric, " + COLUMN_SET_SIX2 + " numeric, " + COLUMN_SET_SEVEN1 + " numeric, " + COLUMN_SET_SEVEN2
             + " numeric, " + COLUMN_RESULT1 + " numeric, " + COLUMN_RESULT2 + " numeric);";
```

this is my method to enter a "PingPongeEntry" into the database

```
public void createPingPongEntry(int lead, String challengeName, String date, String place, int set11, int set12, int set21, int set22,
            int set31, int set32, int set41, int set42, int set51, int set52, int set61, int set62, int set71, int set72, int tot1, int tot2){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LEAD, lead);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CNAME, challengeName);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE, date);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PLACE, place);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_ONE1, set11);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_ONE2, set12);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_TWO1, set21);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_TWO2, set22);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_THREE1, set31);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_THREE2, set32);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_FOUR1, set41);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_FOUR2, set42);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_FIVE1, set51);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_FIVE2, set52);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_SIX1, set61);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_SIX2, set62);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_SEVEN1, set71);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_SEVEN2, set72);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_RESULT1, tot1);
        values.put(CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_RESULT2, tot2);

        long insertID = database.insert(CustomSQLiteHelper.TABLE_PINGPONG, null, values);

        Cursor cursor = database.query(CustomSQLiteHelper.TABLE_PINGPONG, allColumns3, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID_RUNNING + " = " + insertID, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        cursor.close();
    }
```

That's the allColums3-String[]

```
private String[] allColumns3 = {CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID_PINGPONG, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CNAME, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PLACE, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LEAD,
                                    CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_ONE1,
                                    CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_ONE2, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_TWO1, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_TWO2, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_THREE1, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_THREE2,
                                    CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_FOUR1, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_FOUR2, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_FIVE1, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_FIVE2, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_SIX1,
                                    CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_SIX2, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_SEVEN1, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SET_SEVEN2, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_RESULT1, CustomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_RESULT2};
```

Now at line `long insertID = database.insert(CustomSQLiteHelper.TABLE_PINGPONG, null, values);` I'm getting the SQLiteConstraintException, and I don't know why. It says:

```
09-29 19:55:13.151: E/Database(1609): Error inserting set51=0 set52=0 set41=3 set61=0 lead=0 set72=0 set71=0 set62=0 date=29-09-2012 result1=4 result2=0 name=pingpong set32=1 set31=3 set42=1 place=hier set22=1 set21=3 set12=1 set11=3
```

(I'm also confused here why there is no order of the inserting values)

I've read a few questions about this topic here, but all recommandation given there are followed: the primary key is autoincremented, and plus at this point, where I'm trying to insert the record, the database is empty.

I have 2 methods to insert `FootBallEntrys` and `Games` by analogy to this, and everything works fine. So why it doesn't create a unique uid here?

Comment: I think you create an unnamed column that must not be null here: `+ COLUMN_DATE + " text not null, " + " text not null,`. You don't provide values for that one when inserting so it fails.

Comment: @zapl While I'm surprised the table even compiles, you should post this as an answer. You would have my upvote.

Comment: it was in fact that piece of code I oversaw. If you post it as answer, of course I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a ConstraintException, you are violating some constraint in the table.
The only rule you have is "Primary key" which creates backstage a "Unique" constraint.
Make sure you are not trying to insert an already existing value in the column "COLUMN_ID_PINGPONG".

Comment: there are also several "NOT NULL" constraints which are more likely the reason.